# Laravel map and filter getting wrong response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have an eager-loading relationship query.

```php
$transactions = User::with(['point','children']->get();
```

Now I am adding a filter on my datatable.

```php
->addColumn('total', function ($user) {
    $sum = 0;
    $filtered = $user->map(function ($user, &$sum) {
        $find = $user->children->filter(function ($children) use ($user) {
            return $children->id == $user->id;
        });
        $sum += $find->point->available;

        return $sum;
    });

    return $sum;
})
```

If any user id matched with children id then the sum of all matched user available point value.

But I am getting this error...

> [15:22:58] LOG.error: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method
>   App\User::map()

Here `$user` is a collection and every user has many children.

Comment: $user is a collection of user or just one user?

Comment: $user is a collection @Thamerbelfkih

Comment: try to collect method first on your filtered var , like $filtered = collect($user); an then $filtered->map...  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map

Comment: What are you calling `addColumn` on?

Comment: I am using yajra datatables @RossWilson

Comment: @RossWilson he's using datatable package

Comment: `$user` is not a collection, but an instance of `App\User`, so just remove the `map`